# .NET Core - MVC - The method 'post' on path '/list' is registered multiple times

Tags: asp.net-core

I have two controllers (LeadsController, PartnersController) with **different routes !!**

I expect the compiler/MVC framework to inject their respective route based on **[Route("api/[controller]")]**

their respective routes are **api/Partners** and **api/Leads**

but since I use the same "/list" endpoint to get a list of items, I get that error

```
The method 'post' on path '/list' is registered multiple times.
```

**it makes no sense, the routes are supposed to be different for each controller**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class LeadsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly Leads2WinDBContext _context;

    public LeadsController(Leads2WinDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // POST: api/Leads/list
    [HttpPost("/list")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Lead>>> GetLeads(LeadsSearch leadsSearch)
    {
        return await _context.Leads.ToListAsync();
    }

    ...
```

the other controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PartnersController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly Leads2WinDBContext _context;

    public PartnersController(Leads2WinDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // POST: api/Partners/list
    [HttpPost("/list")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Partner>>> GetPartners(PartnersSearch partnersSearch)
    {
        return await _context.Partners.ToListAsync();
    }
```

what do I do wrong ?

thanks for your help

[edit:

```
<PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.4.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.7" />
<PackageReference Include="NSwag.AspNetCore" Version="13.7.0" />
<PackageReference Include="NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.7.1" />
```

]

Comment: Are you using asp.net core?

Comment: yes, but I use mvc too (and entity), I approved your edit

Comment: Remove the leading slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mention 'list' in `Route` not in HttpPost, because that's in your route

```
    // POST: api/Leads/list
    [HttpPost()]
    [Route("list")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Leads>>> GetPartners(LeadsSearch leadsSearch)
    {
```

```
    // POST: api/Partners/list
    [HttpPost()]
    [Route("list")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Partner>>> GetPartners(PartnersSearch partnersSearch)
    {
```